# Masking my IP address when using `wget` or `curl`

Tags: ip, curl, wget, download

I am trying to access/download a file on an old server which has geolocation restriction. I was just wondering if I can use `wget` or `curl` on macOS and change my ip address so that the old server allows download. I know I can use VPN/Proxy but I am interested to know if there is generally a simpler way.

Comment: Nope. A download is a request for the server to send you something. So the server needs your correct ip to know where to send the data.

Comment: You could check out `tor` and use `torsocks curl ...` , but not sure how to force geo. It would of course not be much different from Proxy

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no.

Long answer is you need to provide your IP address in the TCP/IP network to facilitate proper routing of packets. Otherwise, you could not receive the data properly.